# C# Vsto Excel , How to Merge ListObject Header

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am looking for a solution thant i can make list object have multiple header.

I wish it will be like  Picture below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPP5f.png)

And My DataSource Will be like

```
public List<SalesList> GetSalesList()
{
    List<SalesList> salesList = new List<SalesList>() {
    new SalesList {ID=1 ,Sales="David" ,Buyer="A INC",  ProductSoldQty= 10,ProductShipQty=  5},
    new SalesList {ID=2 ,Sales="Jonny" ,Buyer="B INC",  ProductSoldQty= 20,ProductShipQty=  20},
    new SalesList {ID=3 ,Sales="Mary " ,Buyer="C INC",  ProductSoldQty= 15,ProductShipQty=  10},
    new SalesList {ID=4 ,Sales="Ruby " ,Buyer="D INC",  ProductSoldQty= 52,ProductShipQty=  20},
    new SalesList { ID=5, Sales="Frank" ,Buyer="E INC",  ProductSoldQty= 30,ProductShipQty=  30}
  };

    return salesList;
}
public class SalesList
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Sales { get; set; }
    public string Buyer { get; set; }
    public int ProductSoldQty { get; set; }
    public int ProductShipQty { get; set; }
}
```

I haven't find any Sample of Multiple Header ListObject .

Is it posible ?

Comment: No, you can't do that with a table in Excel. Does it have to be a table?

Comment: Thank you for reply . Is is ok to input without table .

Comment: but listobject and DataTable seems to be  fastest way to import data .

Comment: It's a very bad practice to merge cells in Excel for processing data  at all, neither with C# nor with excel itself.